# Swift convert int nsmanagedobject to .text

Tags: swing, nsnumber

I have a cordite model. One of the attributes is an NSNumber,

```
@NSManaged var playerOneScore: NSNumber
```

I'm trying to fetch this and store it in a text label.

```
playerOnePar.text = myArray[0].valueForKey("playerOneScore") as String
```

It doesn't like this. Im guessing an NSNumber can't be casted into a String. However, it doesn't like this. Thoughts on this with the new swift language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Swift automatically bridges certain native number types, such as Int and Float, to NSNumber.`

Ok, Try this out , I tested this and worked as expacted.

```
    let number: NSNumber = myArray[0].valueForKey("playerOneScore")
    let intNumber: Int = number
    playerOnePar.text = String(intNumber)
```